# How to retrieve certain childByAutoId() key

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have looked around for a while, with no luck. I need to get the string value of a certain dictionary key in firebase.

If you look at the image below,I need that key on top, and need to set it equal to a string, that I can segue to other viewcontrollers so when a user wants to make a post under the sharers for example, I go into the right value based on the key, then to sharers, where I can add values. Thanks, also I do not need all values, just once I have observedWithSingleEvent, I need to get the key of each page or dictionary.

[image]

my code:

```
    let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
    ref.child("Notes").queryOrderedByKey().observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
        if let pagers = snapshot.value as? [String : AnyObject] {
           let numb = snapshot.key //what I want
            for (_, val) in pagers {
                if let useri = val["postUsername"] as? String {
                    if useri == FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid {

                        let bindfl = Page()
                        if let title = val["title"] as? String, let descript = val["description"] as? String,
                            let sharers = val["sharers"] as? [String], let poster = val["postUsername"] as? String, let setter = val["setter"] as? String, let creatorName = val["creatorName"] as? String {
                            bindfl.title = title
                            bindfl.descriptions = descript
                            bindfl.setter = setter
                            bindfl.sharers = sharers
                            bindfl.usernameOfBinder = poster
                            bindfl.creatorName = creatorName
                            bindfl.theBit = numb

                            self.pages.append(bindfl)
```

Comment: Please edit your question. It's really hard to understand. What do you seek actually?

Comment: got it UmarZaii

Comment: What do you mean by _set it equal to string_?

Comment: I just need the string value of the key

Comment: the individual, randomly generated key for that dictionary

Comment: It's kinda hard to understand. Can you include image of your current result as well as your desired result?

Comment: umar I cleaned it up

Comment: Nice now I can understand clearly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150546/discussion-between-umarzaii-and-nivix).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can do it like this, when you add data to the database

```
let key = ref.("Notes").childByAutoId().key
let notes = ["userName": userName,
            "description": description,
            "title": title,
            "author": author,
            "keyID": key]
let childUpdates = ["/Notes/\(key)": notes]
ref.updateChildValues(childUpdates)
```

After that you can, get the key like this

```
bindfl.title = title
bindfl.descriptions = descriptions
bindfl.userName = userName
bindfl.author= author
bindfl.keyID= keyID
```

Hope it worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
ref.child("Notes"). observeSingleEvent(of: .childAdded, with: {snapshot in
   print("\(snapshot.key)")
})
```

Will give you the autoID key of every entry in the table

```
ref.child("Notes").queryOrdered(byChild: "creatorName").queryEqual(toValue: "posterName").observeSingleEvent(of: .childAdded, with: {snapshot in
     var postID = snapshot.key

  //update post different post using retrieved ID
     let infoToAdd = ["newPostStuff" : true]
     FIREBASE_REF!.child("Posts/\(postID)").updateChildValues(infoToAdd)
})
```

Will give you the auto ID of every post by a given creator and then update values on a different table with the retrieved key

Comment: is there a way to get a certain key for a post after I have used the observesingleeventtype

Comment: Im not sure what you mean. The print statement executes after the observeSingleEvent function

Comment: ref.child("Notes").queryOrderedByKey().observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
        if let pagers = snapshot.value as? [String : AnyObject] {
           let numb = snapshot.key //what I want. I only need the the key of the snapshot.value

Comment: You want to only retrieve that key and nothing else? If so im not sure there is a way to do it. Im pretty sure Firebase only returns dictionaries with a key and a value.

Comment: how am I supposed to add values under a dictionary in a separate view controller then?

Comment: retrieve the dictionary and extract the key like the example above, then inside of the observeSingleEvent function, update info to the desired table. Ill update my code.